# Error en decodificación utf-8 en Laravel

Tags: laravel

Genero una consulta a mi BD y extraigo algunos datos que paso a una vista en la cual genero un PDF, el problema que me surge es al momento de imprimir mis registros en mi campo de **observacion** dentro de mi vista me imprime algunos campos vacíos, al estar revisando por que me aparece ese problema es que en la BD se guarda con acentos y ñ algunos registros y al extraerlos me genera el error, se que eso se arregla con la etiqueta

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

pero como genero mi vista en html que va dirigido a PDF no respeta mi etiqueta y no se de que manera pueda hacer que me respete los caracteres especiales y me los imprima sin problema, intente esta manera que encontré en internet pero creo que la genero mal

```
$inventario = Inventario::all();

$inventario = utf8_decode($inventario);
```

En la vista genero mi consulta con Laravel

```
 @foreach($inventario as $dato)
       <table id="table">
        <tr>
         <td>{{ucfirst(strtolower($dato->nombre))}}</td>
         <td>{{ucfirst(strtolower($dato->observacion))}}</td>
         <td>$ {{$dato->precio}}</td>
        </tr>
       </table>
  @endforeach
```

no se que otra manera lo podría lograr, agradecería de su apoyo.

Comment: ¿nombre es una función/método también? veo que recibe un parámetro de entrada.

Comment: Lo lamento era un error **nombre** es el campo de mi BD del cual extraigo el nombre de mi producto